# Angular 7, create import annotation (decorator?)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm not sure what these are called but I want to create a custom annotation for imports. For example, I can do the following anywhere in my project:

```
import { SomeComponent } from '@app/components/some.component';
```

I'm talking about the `@app` part. No matter what file I'm in, `@app` will always take me to the `src/app` folder. How do I make my own?

If I had a file inside `project/foo/bar/myfile.ts`, how can I create an annotation that says `@bar` which takes them to the "bar" folder no matter where they are in the project folder structure.

I want to be able to do this:

```
import { MyFile } from '@bar/myfile';
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You can configure custom prefixes for imports in your tsconfig under the `paths` object. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like what you're trying to do is to have a shorter path that you can import code from.

This can be done with the `paths` property of your TypeScript configuration file (usually `tsconfig.json`) (see the [module resolution handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) for more info on the `paths` property).

See below for an example (P.s. don't copy the comments as it is invalid syntax for JSON files):

```json
{
  // ...
  "paths": {
    "@app": [
      "./app"
    ],
    // Needed to resolve secondary paths
    "@app/*": [
      "./app/*"
    ]
  }
}
```